# Intento usar ```pygame.init()``` y me da error diciendo que pygame no esta definido

Tags: pygame

Llevo un rato peleandome con colab ya que intento hacer `pygame.init()` y me da error constantemente. También he probado `pygame.display.init()` ya que en foros angloparlantes recomendaban probarlo. Igual estoy intentando hacer algo sin sentido, me tocará pagar la novatada supongo...

Answer (score 0):

`pygame` no está instalado por defecto en las maquinas de colab, tienes que ejecutar tú la instalación para usarlo. Con esto te debería valer:

```
!pip install pygame

import pygame
pygame.init()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!